# Django override_settings won't work for running multiple tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, django-nose

I am getting a bit odd behavior using the `override_settings` decorator. It basically works when I run the test alone, but won't work if I run the whole testing suite.

In this test I am changing the `REST_FRAMEWORK` options, because when running this suite I want to set the authentication settings, with the other tests do not use authentication:

```
@override_settings(REST_FRAMEWORK=AUTH_REST_FRAMEWORK)
class AuthTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(AuthTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.client = Client()

    def test_i_need_login(self):
        response = client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401)
```

so if I do...

`$ python manage.py test myapp/tests/test_auth.py`

The settings are applied and works great!

but if run the whole testing suite like:

`$ python manage.py test`

The test will fail. It seems to me that these settings (or some objects) are being cached from other tests. I also have another class in another test file that uses a Client instance in similar way.

Environment:
`Python: 2.7`
`Django: 1.10`

**Edit:**

The workaround I found to this problem was to use find to run the tests, it can be an alias or a script with...

`find . -name 'test*.py' -exec python manage.py test {} \;`

The downside is that the output of many tests gets piled up in the screen and it may create/destroy test database a few times. Unless you add options to the command like REUSE_DB if using django-nose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, there is a [warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/) about this very situation.

> Warning
>
> The settings file contains some settings that are only consulted
>   during initialization of Django internals. If you change them with
>   override_settings, the setting is changed if you access it via the
>   django.conf.settings module, however, Django’s internals access it
>   differently. Effectively, using override_settings() or
>   modify_settings() with these settings is probably not going to do what
>   you expect it to do.

The first time you run the tests, you are running a specific test case so the override takes effect. The second time you run the test, you are running a whole suite and your specific testcase probably isn't the first one that's being run. So the above happens.

Comment: There is way around this?? maybe by reloading the module.

Comment: You will have to write a custom test runner but it's not going to be easy

Comment: This warning is present in Django: 2.2 as well as the version in the original post.